# tpl inside of Items[] on Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying to add this code in Sencha Touch, but it´s not working..

```
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'label',
            tpl: ['<div class="label">{[c.Text.getText("SC_ORDER_A_TOTAL_NET_AMOUNT")]} </div>'    +
                '<div class="total-value">{netamount}</div>' +
                '<div class="indicator {lightstatus}">{lightvalue}</div>'].join()
        }
    ]
```

Maybe, it´s not possible to do this.. any clue? I need to configure different labels with different hidden option, sometimes it´s true and sometimes it´s false.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
{
    xtype: 'label',
    tpl: '<tpl if="doShow"><div style="color:red;">It is raining {textFromData}</div></tpl>',
    data: {textFromData:'Cats and Dogs'}
}
```

Comment: thanks Proto Bassi, do you know if it is possible to add the property hidden in this context?

Comment: hidden:true  works for me too. (Tested it on a container with vbox) and using the following worked too: Ext.Viewport.down('label').setHidden(false)

Comment: Example is good, but It is not working for me, I don´t need to add hidden property, I am receiving from a json webservice the configuration of each field, in a tpl if I should get the hidden property from this json

Comment: Ahh ok. I added to the example the doShow. If that returns true from the server than show the content otherwise show nowthing. But that is actually already covered in other stackoverflow questions. Usually you get downrated for such questions.